# how to refresh browser automatically using cgi + python

Tags: python, html, cgi

i have form.html and form.py files. In form.html file i have a text box and a button when i enter some keyword in the text box and submit it, it executes form.py based on the keyword entered and it displays latest tweets from twitter. now my requirement is to refresh broswer automatically for every 5 sec to get latest tweets.

i have tried meta http-equiv="refresh" content='5' but it is refreshing only form.py without taking keyword from form.html

is there any way to do it, please suggest me....

Answer (score 0):

When you 1st call form.py, send an header to set a cookie with the keyword, then on subsequent refreshes you should get the cookie and not the keyword as post daya, so read it from there.

In case both post data and cookie are present you should ignore the cookie and treat it as just post data and set the new cookie in the HTTP headers.

To set a cookie you must send an header like this

```
Set-Cookie: name=value
```

or like this to have an expiration

```
Set-Cookie: name2=value2; Expires=Wed, 09-Jun-2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

I think in the 1st case the cookie would be treated as a session cookie, and be removed when you close the browser.

Check the python doc to see how to set and read headers with the CGI module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please tell me how to send an header to a cookie.

Comment: Thanks for the syntax but what will be the name, value in set-cookie header. And one more doubt is the above set-cookie syntax is enough to refresh the browser automatically.

Comment: The way you are refreshing the page is correct, the problem that you have is that POST data is not sent again upon refresh.

Comment: I am using this syntax Set-Cookie: searchkeyword=searchterm, where searchkeyword is the name & searchterm is the value. But i am getting syntax error is there any wrong in my code.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong, but how am i supposed to know without seeing?